# Do I need an .htacess with 301 redirects for the same domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I have had a website for a couple of years, and this year I decided to update it completely. Most of the content is going to stay but there are some pages that will disappear and I'm adding some new ones. The whole site's design has changed though. When I launch this new site, is it required to create an .htaccess with 301 redirects file? Any help will be much appretiated.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need rewrite or redirection rules if you need to rewrite or redirect something. Do you need that?